Vue dragable elements reordering with different containers
I develop an application in VueJs 3, and need the following behavior:
There is a main list of chapters, and in each chapter there are events:
- Chapter 1
    - Event 1
    - Event 2
         :
 - Chapter 2
    - Event 6
    - Event 7
         :

I want user to be able to reorder events by dragging them into the place he wants.
It also means that the first event of a chapter might be dragged to be the last one in the chapter before:

I found the jquery sortable library, which does what I need, I wonder if there any Vue library or adaption for it.

You can try with vue-draggable-plus, which support vue3 and is very active.
According to the documentation, you could achieve it via setting the same group name to the 2 lists.
online demo
<template>
  <div>
    <h6>List 1</h6>
    <VueDraggable v-model="list" animation="150" group="items" class="container">
      <div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" class="item">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </VueDraggable>
    <h6>List 2</h6>
    <VueDraggable v-model="lista" animation="150" group="items" class="container">
      <div v-for="item in lista" :key="item.id" class="item">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </VueDraggable>
  </div>
</template>


I reviewed it and it is what I am looking for, thanks! One doubt - I can get new index of dragged element from the event param, but cannot figure out how to detect whether it was moved to another group.

@guyaloni According to the documentation, if you specify the two lists with the same group name, it should be ok to drag between to lists.

I found vue-draggable-next
It it based on sortable.js, but doesn't seem to be under active development (as of 2024-08).
Drag and drop shouldn't be hard to implement yourself though.
Maybe you can fork this library and adjust it to your needs as you go?

I don't find there a possibility to group items as I mentioned in the question.

It has it, under 'nested', right here: https://vue-draggable-next.vercel.app/#/nested
You can either drag Chapters, Events, or Chapters and Events. By making components draggable or not and adding them to groups.
This implements your specific example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-n969z4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTestList.vue
